# PIP fails downloading any package due to checksums

Tags: python, pip

I have a issue with PIP, I am not able to download any package, getting an error like:

```
ERROR: THESE PACKAGES DO NOT MATCH THE HASHES FROM THE REQUIREMENTS FILE. If you have updated the package versions, please update the hashes. Otherwise, examine the package contents carefully; someone may have tampered with them.
pyspark from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8e/b0/bf9020b56492281b9c9d8aae8f44ff51e1bc91b3ef5a884385cb4e389a40/pyspark-3.0.0.tar.gz#sha256=8c6e5cc51d91eb8d43e81d0b7093292b5e144ac81445491d5f887d2cf4fe121f:
    Expected sha256 8c6e5cc51d91eb8d43e81d0b7093292b5e144ac81445491d5f887d2cf4fe121f
         Got        8193e8eb19deb43aec4a342f758fe36429546d095f4d4b1a841cd98185b2a7b0
```

I have already removed and reinstalled both Python and PiP without any success.
I have also tried using `--no-cache-dir` but the error still remains.

EDIT: I'm running Ubuntu Server 18.04 on VirtualBox in Windows 10

Comment: can you access other webpages from your VM?

Comment: yes, internet connection is working

Comment: Can you please provide the steps and command you are using to generate this issue?

Comment: Running 'pip install <any package>' generates always an error like the one in the main post

Comment: You can try using wget "https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8e/b0/bf9020b56492281b9c9d8aae8f44ff51e1bc91b3ef5a884385cb4e389a40/pyspark-3.0.0.tar.gz". This is going to download the file in your local.

Comment: are you using pipenv?